# React Native React Navigation screen does not redirect after login with AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-navigation, asyncstorage

So I built a login system with React Native, React Navigation and AsyncStorage. If the user clicks on a button he gets logged in and the value of the AsyncStorage Key "@loginuser" gets refreshed. Now I expected
that the screen automatically gets refreshed, but I have to close the App and start it again - This is not optimal.

(I also saw [React-Native/React navigation redirection after login with redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509167/react-native-react-navigation-redirection-after-login-with-redux) post, but it is very old)

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import DefaultStackNavigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';


const App = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <DefaultStackNavigation />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Navigation.js

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
//React Native
import { Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
//Screens
import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen/HomeScreen'
import AddScreen from "../AddScreen/AddScreen";
import NotificationScreen from "../NotificationScreen/NotificationScreen";
import MenuScreen from "../MenuScreen/MenuScreen";
import SearchScreen from "../SearchScreen/SearchScreen";
import PostJobScreen from "../PostJobScreen/PostJobScreen";
import JobOfferScreen from "../JobOfferScreen/JobOfferScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "../ProfileScreen/ProfileScreen";
import NoneLoggedinScreen from "../NoneLoggedinScreen/NoneLoggedinScreen"
import SignupModal from "../NoneLoggedinScreen/SignupModal"
//React Navigation
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
//Third Party
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';




const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

//Tab bar
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{style:{height: 50}}, {showIcon: true}, {showLabel: false}} >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchJobStack}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="AddScreen" component={AddScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="NotificationScreen" component={NotificationScreen} />}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="MenuScreen" component={MenuScreen}/>}}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const STORAGE_KEY = '@loginStatus'

const DefaultStackNavigation = () => {

  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState()
  const readData = async () => {
    try {
      const isLoggedIn = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY))
      console.log(isLoggedIn)
      if (isLoggedIn !== null) {
        setLoginStatus(isLoggedIn)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage')
    }
  }

  readData()

  return loginStatus ? (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} independent={false}>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="PostJobScreen" component={PostJobScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) : (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} independent={false}>
        <Stack.Screen name="NoneLoggedinScreen" component={NoneLoggedinScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignupModal" component={SignupModal} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};


export default DefaultStackNavigation;
```

NoneLoggedinScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const STORAGE_KEY = '@loginStatus'

const SignupModal = () => {

  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false)
  const saveData = async (parmLoginStatus) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(parmLoginStatus))
      alert('Data successfully saved -> Logged In')
      console.log(loginStatus)
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed to save the data to the storage')
    }
  }

  const onSubmitLogin = () => {
    setLoginStatus(true)
    saveData(true)
  }


  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Login Page. Press the button to log in and stay logged in</Text>
      <Button title="Log in" onPress={() => onSubmitLogin()}/>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  App: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
});

export default SignupModal;
```

Now I was expecting the page to reload and I can use the app. Unfortunately it doesn't. The data is saved and the login status is set to `true`, but I have to restart the app to use it. The perfidious thing is, if I write the AsyncStorage login logic from the `NoneLoggedinScreen.js` file into the App.js file, the app works fine -> However, this is not an alternative for me, because the general structure of the app is, I think, built relatively sensibly.
Also when the user tries to be redirected manually (by button) with navigation.navigate("HomeTabs") after logging in doesn't work, and I get an error that Home doesn't exist, which is also not understandable, because the navigation has actually been set to Logged in now. Has anyone ever had this problem?

This are my dependencies by the way

```
"dependencies": {<br>
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.1",<br>
  "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",<br>
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.7",<br>
  "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.2",<br>
  "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.2",<br>
  "react": "16.13.1",<br>
  "react-native": "0.63.4",<br>
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.1",<br>
  "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",<br>
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",<br>
  "react-native-screens": "^2.17.1",<br>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your authentication strategy, there is a hidden assumption that when you save data using AsyncStorage in `NoneLoggedInScreen`, the data will immediately be read using the `readData` function in `DefaultStackNavigation`. The reason why this does not happen is that `readData` is only called when `DefaultStackNavigation` renders/re-renders. This will not happen when one of its children sets some data in local storage.

There are many ways to fix this. Using redux with redux-persist or another state-management and persistence setup, or a purpose-built context-based solution (see eg. this Kent C. Dodds article on [Authentication in React Applications](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/authentication-in-react-applications)).

---

The second, minor issue that you mention:

> navigation.navigate("HomeTabs") after logging in doesn't work, and I get an error that Home doesn't exist

does make sense, and the reason behind it is that you conditionally render two different `NavigationContainers`. They don't know about each others routes, so you can't navigate between them.

To fix this, you should render one `NavigationContainer` and conditionally render one of the `Stack.Navigator`s as its child.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it's the normal way to do it?

Comment: Well, it's a broader architectural choice - in case of redux/mobx and similar it will dictate how you write your state management, components, and business logic. You might want to look at a few options and choose the one that makes most sense.

Comment: Okey. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

To manage authentication flow in a smooth way we should make two seperate navigators for the navigation. I find this workflow the best as of now. It works perfectly and is clean.
So what I usually do in my Projects that I create two navigators `AuthNavigator.js` and `AppNavigator.js` and then use conditional rendering.

So what you can do is create a folder called `navigation` where your `App.js` is located. Then inside `navigation` folder create two files called `AppNavigator.js` and `AuthNavigator.js`.

Your `AuthNavigator.js` should look like this

```
import React from "react";
import NoneLoggedinScreen from "../NoneLoggedinScreen/NoneLoggedinScreen";
import SignupModal from "../NoneLoggedinScreen/SignupModal";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} independent={false}>
      <Stack.Screen name="NoneLoggedinScreen" component={NoneLoggedinScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SignupModal" component={SignupModal} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AuthNavigator;
```

Your `AppNavigator.js` should look like this

```
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "../HomeScreen/HomeScreen";
import AddScreen from "../AddScreen/AddScreen";
import NotificationScreen from "../NotificationScreen/NotificationScreen";
import MenuScreen from "../MenuScreen/MenuScreen";
import PostJobScreen from "../PostJobScreen/PostJobScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "../ProfileScreen/ProfileScreen";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

//Tab bar
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={
        ({ style: { height: 50 } }, { showIcon: true }, { showLabel: false })
      }
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchJobStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="AddScreen" component={AddScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="NotificationScreen" component={NotificationScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="MenuScreen" component={MenuScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} independent={false}>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeTabs} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PostJobScreen" component={PostJobScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

And your `App.js` should look like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import AuthStorage from './auth/storage';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import AuthNavigator from './navigation/AuthNavigator';

const App = () => {
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);

  // I am using useEffect hook but I would prefer using `AppLoading` to restore token if it exists
  useEffect(() => {
    readData();
  }, []);

  const readData = async () => {
    try {
      const isLoggedIn = JSON.parse(await AuthStorage.getItem());
      console.log(isLoggedIn);
      if (isLoggedIn !== null) {
        setLoginStatus(isLoggedIn);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage');
    }
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {loginStatus ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Create a folder called `auth` where your `App.js` is located. Inside that create a file called `storage.js`. Now inside `storage.js` paste this code

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const AuthToken = '@loginStatus';

const storeItem = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(AuthToken, JSON.stringify(value));
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};

const getItem = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(AuthToken);
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};

export default { storeItem, getItem };
```

Comment: I have still the same problem :/

Comment: Check out this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/authentication-workflow). I implemented it and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah, in general it works fine, but if I change the value of `@loginStatus` per Button or what else it wont refresh